# Rationale to convert a question to community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Some weeks ago I asked this [big-list question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501320). It was converted into community wiki only 6 minutes later, without giving any notification or comment. Frankly speaking, I wasn't too enthusiastic about that. Of course, corrections to my question are always welcome, but I wanted it still to be *my* question, without the community wiki label inviting others to freely change the content.

Searching the discussions on Meta, I found out that it seems to be some kind of a convention to make big-list questions community wiki.

Yesterday, a [new big-list question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532544) of quite similar nature was posted. But it wasn't made community wiki. What's the difference here?

**Edit**:
Now the second question is community wiki, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I see it, the **major** difference is that one question was almost immediately flagged by some user to be made CW, and the other wasn't similarly flagged for 1 day, 11 hours, 14 minutes and 49 seconds (or thereabouts) after being posted.

I will note that the time between the flag and conversion to CW isn't much different between the two questions.

This is to say, at least on the moderator side of things I see no evidence that the two questions were treated differently.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I do not see *any* reason to turn any question into CW.

Why would we want to not recognize the effort put by a user in coming up with an answer?!

The idea that CW applies when the question «does not have *one* answer» has always seemed incomprehensible to me. That a question may have many possible answers somehow makes each answer less valuable?

Comment: I am [aufkag](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/532544/56801) and I approve this message.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I've long thought the same way, but am just a peon. Alas!

Answer (score 3):

And then this happens:

> [image]
>   [image]

So, there is a demonstrable negative effect on the quality and quantity of the answers after turning a question into CW.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Some users are in it for the points. Even if they have a potentially good answer, they will simply not be bothered. That might actually be _the_ reason for _some_ people not to be interested in CW questions.

Comment: Ah! I did not see the image before.